# Is it always possible to achieve perfect accuracy on a small dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, overfitting, train

I have read many times that a good debugging step while building a machine learning model is to try to overfit your model to a very small subset of your data. [Here is one such instance][1].

Provided your code is bug free, is it always possible to achieve perfect or near-perfect performance on the training set when you do this? Could you do it even on a small dataset of random numbers?

I have a model that is achieving significantly better accuracy on my actual data than it does if I feed it random numbers, but its far from perfect, and it seems no matter how small I make the dataset, how many layers I use, or how big I make the layers, the accuracy stays about the same. What could cause this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to folks who responded, I understand that it should always be possible to fit a small subset of your data, so I took another look at my implementation.

It turned out there were several small issues. Switching from random uniform weight initialization to xavier initialization provided a significant bump in my results (I assumed this would only improve the speed at which training would converge to the same crappy result, but it actually improved the accuracy overall). I also did not have fully normalized data. Everything was in a range from 0 to ~10, which I initially thought should be good enough, but I got another big bump in performance when I normalized to -1 to 1. A third problem I had was with my validation set. My data is in several different sets from different sources, and it turned out there were distinct "styles" or trends to each set. I was training on a majority of the datasets, and evaluating on one particular set. When I shuffled all the individual examples together from all sets, and then drew my validation set randomly from the complete shuffled set, I started seeing accuracies in the mid and upper 90s!

Comment: Models with more parameters than data often (always?)  have multiple exact solutions. If your implementation cant find one of them, look for bugs.

Comment: Obvs set regularization hyperparameters to zero when trying this, and don't assume that finding a perfect fit absolves you of all bugs. Bugs in the gradient can slow fitting, while still climbing down the loss function due to ratcheting effects that may be built into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, there is nothing a neural network can't approximate. In fact, you only need a single hidden layer!

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

So the answer is definitely YES, it's always possible to achieve perfect or near-perfect performance for any training data set. No matter how small or how big.

Have you:

- Actually looked at the training examples that your network failed? Maybe there's a pattern?

It's no good randomly adjust neural network paramters. You said your new dataset is small, why don't you work a bit harder, and pull the training sets that your network can't predict/classify? There should be a reason, maybe you have a bug? Maybe those examples are just non-sense or outliers?? Maybe they are just random noise that your network shouldn't work on it anyway? Maybe you just need more iterations?

Please look at those failed examples, don't guess. Machine learning is more than just running the same thing again and again.

Comment: I think the statement about the universal approximation theorem needs some important qualifications. 1) The theorem doesn't say that a neural net can approximate anything. There are conditions that the function must obey for the theorem to hold. 2) The theorem only covers the *existence* of good approximators. It doesn't give any guarantees that they can be learned. 3) Depending on the function, a good approximation may require an arbitrarily large network.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is difficult to answer in the abstract but for what it is worth here are some thoughts:

The data you are feeding the might not be the 'perfect' dataset for that particular algorithm. For example, I could estimate the parameters of a linear regression model (i.e., $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$) using stochastic gradient descent. If the data is inconsistent with my assumption (e.g., the data points are randomly scattered around then the fit is likely to be poor with a small dataset. In your context, it is possible that the neural network approach may be getting too many 'disparate' data points which are wildly different in some sense (e.g., if we are trying to recover handwritten digits then it gets images of handwritten digits written in different colors, with different writing instruments etc.). Thus, with a small dataset the fit is poor but as you increase the dataset size, more training samples become available and the fit improves as one might expect.

The only circumstance when I imagine the fit would be good with a small dataset would be when we have a well-behaved dataset in the sense that there is a strong pattern that can be recovered easily by our model. For example, we feed the neural network handwritten digits all written in black with about the same font size by the same type of writing instrument and so on. In such a situation, I would imagine that a small dataset might be sufficient and a sufficiently complex neural network might actually fit the data perfectly as the pattern in the data is too strong relative to the noise present.